# iOS 5.0: current device orientation in view did load returns 0

Tags: ipad, ios5, viewdidload, uideviceorientation

Could someone please tell me why [UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] always returns 0 in view did load? I want to change the layout of my screen based on current orientation. It doesn't work when I keep my device in landscap mode initially. I am expecting [UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] to return landscap orientation in that case but it doesn't. It gives right values then onwards! Could someone please help me to identify what's the issue. Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self resizeContentViews:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
}
```

Comment: Begin and Ending Rotation events doesn't make any different!

Comment: You are right. Checking Status bar orientation worked for me. Probably other didn't work because I was testing on Simulator. Please put this as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks.